# Excel create table with all combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's assume I have 3 columns with labels

1. A B C D
2. a b c d e
3. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Is there a quick and easy way to create an empty table with all permutations? i.e.

- A - a - 1
- A - a - 2
- ....
- D - e - 10

Comment: Why does this look to me like a school homework assignment?

Comment: No worries, it's for work and I'm trying to automatize cumbersome copy paste tasks as I might be required to redo this several times in the future

Comment: Clearly worded question that solved my exact problem. Thank you. Well asked questions don't get enough upvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running this short macro:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, N As Long

    N = 1
    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 5
            For k = 1 To 10
                Cells(N, 4) = Cells(i, 1) & "-" & Cells(j, 2) & "-" & Cells(k, 3)
                N = N + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce a column of the desired 200 combinations:

[image]

Comment: after long search your way is the easiest if the person can write code

Comment: @shadysherif  Thank you, I also like Scott's answer

Comment: In my case I have data in different sheets.that's why this answer is the best for me.

Comment: Exactly!  These are COMBINATIONS, not permutations.  If they were permutations, you would include A-a-1, A-1-a, a-A-1, etc...

Answer (score 13):

EDIT:

With Office 365 we can make this more elastic:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:C10,
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    arr,MAKEARRAY(rw^clm,clm,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(rng,INT(MOD(a, rw ^ b) / (rw^ b / rw))+1,b)&"")),
    end,FILTER(arr,MMULT(--(arr=""),SEQUENCE(clm,,1,0))=0),
    SORT(IF(ISNUMBER(--end),--end,end),SEQUENCE(,clm)))
```

This will take ranges of any size as long as `#ofRows^#ofColumns` does not exceed the number of rows on the sheet:

[image]

Then for the joined version we use BYROW and TEXTJOIN:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:C10,
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    arr,MAKEARRAY(rw^clm,clm,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(rng,INT(MOD(a, rw ^ b) / (rw^ b / rw))+1,b)&"")),
    end,FILTER(arr,MMULT(--(arr=""),SEQUENCE(clm,,1,0))=0),
    rd,SORT(IF(ISNUMBER(--end),--end,end),SEQUENCE(,clm)),
    BYROW(rd,LAMBDA(p,TEXTJOIN(" - ",,p))))
```

---

Original older version:

You can do this with a formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/((COUNTA(B:B)*(COUNTA(C:C)))))+1)&" - "&INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/COUNTA(C:C)),COUNTA(B:B))+1)&" - "&INDEX(C:C,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),COUNTA(C:C))+1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: got an error in the formulas