# Variation on "Excel create table with all combinations"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a similar question to this [Excel create table with all combinations](https://superuser.com/questions/1194312/excel-create-table-with-all-combinations) I'm looking to do the same (Provide all combinations of each row variable) but reference the Variable column value. Like this:

[image: Sample]

Much appreciated.

Trying to display all unique combinations of the set. Here is a better image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VtLf.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated as requested.